# Lodash _.result() default value

Tags: javascript, lodash

Why doesn't lodash [result](https://lodash.com/docs#result) method return the default value in this case?

> Arguments
>   object (Object): The object to query.
>
> key (string): The key of the property to resolve.
>
> **[defaultValue] (*): The value returned if the property value resolves to undefined.**

```
var result = _.result({ foo: 1 }, 'bar', 'default');

console.log(typeof _.result({ foo: 1 }, 'bar') === 'undefined') // true

console.log(result); // expected: 'default'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbvs5ney/

Comment: Have you tried `_.constant('default')` like they've got in the example?

Comment: @Andy No, I haven't. I'm using the `busy` example just above that as you can see.

Comment: I can get it to work in my browser with your code (that fiddle doesn't work for some reason).

Comment: What version of `lodash` do you use?

Comment: @Kiril 2.2.1 as you see in the Fiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems that the `default` parameter was added only in version 3.0.0
Compare the `_.result` implementation:
**3.0.0** [lodash.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.0.0/lodash.js#L8857)

```
function result(object, key, defaultValue) {
  var value = object == null ? undefined : object[key];
  if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
    value = defaultValue;
  }
  return isFunction(value) ? value.call(object) : value;
}
```

And **2.2.1** [lodash.js](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.2.1/lodash.js#L6057):

```
function result(object, property) {
  if (object) {
    var value = object[property];
    return isFunction(value) ? object[property]() : value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice finding. But there is no need to check the source code in these cases. Lodash has documentation of older versions too (just use the dropdown with the version number at the top of the docs). Here are the docs of the [version 2.4.2 of `_.result`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.2/doc/README.md#_resultobject-key) which shows no `defaultValue` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try with newer lodash version, if you do not need specifically with version 2.2.1.